# HUGO, React, Sass - big project setup

Tags: reactjs, sass, setup-project, hugo

has anyone used a HUGO static site generator with Sass and React framework?
How did you do the setup for a big project?
I the approach described here:
https://www.wictorwilen.se/blog/how-to-add-a-react-script-to-hugo/
But I did have some trouble setting all up to work, for example imports and using js.Build hugo pipeline to minify JS.
I got it to work, but I am not completely happy with this, I think there is a better way.. something more production ready for a big project.

How I do it at the moment:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

{{ $component1 := resources.Get "/scripts/components/component1.js" }}
{{ $component2 := resources.Get "/scripts/components/component2.js" }}
{{ $component3 := resources.Get "/scripts/components/component3.js" }}
{{ $component4 := resources.Get "/scripts/components/component4.js" }}
{{ $bundleItems := slice $component1 $component2 $component3 $component4 }}
{{ $reactBundleJs := $bundleItems | resources.Concat "scripts/bundle.js" | babel }}
<script type="module" defer src="{{ $reactBundleJs.RelPermalink }}"></script>

{{/* TODO -> minify JS */}}
{{ $app := resources.Get "scripts/app.jsx" | resources.ExecuteAsTemplate "app.js" . | babel  }}
<script type="module" src="{{ $app.RelPermalink }}"></script>
```

For the CSS/Sass I am just using ordinary Sass and hugo setup.

If you have any better ideas how to properly setup React and HUGO, please share, I would greatly appreciate it.